# spree installation error (no method error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

can't install spree on new rails project. i'll try both way on instruction

1) manually add spree gem to gemfile and start

```
rails g spree:install --sample=false --seed=false
```

2) start spree auto generator

```
rails _4.1.8_ new my_store
spree install my_store
```

installation is stop with error

```
undefined method `promotions=' for #<Spree::Core::Environment:0x00000004fd6598> (NoMethodError)
```

any suggestion?
P.S. ruby 2.2.0, imagemagick installed correctly. I tried in rails 4.1.8, and 4.2.0, ubuntu 14

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the my_store root when you install spree
eg:

`c:\> rails _4.1.8_ new my_store`

`c:\> cd my_store`

`c:\my_store> spree install my_store`

Comment: hello! i'll doing all by instruction, but thx for answer. P.S. my os is ubuntu 14.

Answer (score 0):

Try ruby 2.1.5. It seems that ruby 2.2.0 is not compatible with current version of spree.

Comment: thx for answer, but there is specific problem only on my computer - we try on my friend computer and all works fine.